# Keep business variables which should define by admin

Tags: software-design

I have multi-vendor project which some variables should set by admin, For instance when User wants to pay his/her cart, fee should be specify and it defined by admin of system. (And it could be change passing of time.)
So what's the best approach for keeping this variables?

**Note:** 
*I'm running server with Nodejs and I use MongoDB as database.*

I have following ideas which has pros and cons in my opinion:

- Save these variables in document (in database), which I guess it's not good since I have to for each payment (or other actions which need these variables) send request to database. These variables seems to be fixed and can change after a while. I mean it's not like a user profile information which could change
  frequently and when user wants to see his/her profile request should send to database. (further more it's just seems not good create new collection for storing just a document)
- Save this in .env file (as environment variables) and I think we keep configuration variables in this file (application layer, not keeping the variables for business) and also updating this file is not good as database.

Please aware me if I make a mistake or there is common way which I don't know. (Also I searched for that and I couldn't find any proper keyword : ( )

Comment: What kind of fee(s) do you take into account ?  VAT ? shipping ? other things ? and for how many countries ? maybee you have more than one, and it could be nice to store this in your database. It seems more suitable than in a .env file.  You can still fetch it only once per user / orde and cache it if needed.

Comment: It's about shipping and I agree with you in future I need more than one but at this state it's fine. You compare two ideas . Is it new way that I don't know about that and maybe  that's common ? @Malo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach has been the following:

- If the values can be updated by business administrator in normal course of operation - then they should have Admin UI and be stored in the database. Fees are a good example.
- If the values hardly ever change; or changed by IT staff - put them in the configuration file. Endpoint of Vendor API, or mail server configuration would go there.